# Adjusting headrule in koma

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I am trying to create a headrule which will start from page end on right side of the page and go till the start of text on the left side.

I am facing two problems,

1. the `headrule` goes all the way across the page (expected as I have set `headwidth=paper` to achieve page number box at end of page. I would like it to be only upto the start of text. (please see the attached screenshot). I have tried using`\KOMAoptions{headsepline=1pt:\linewidth}` option, but starts at the left side of the page and ends before it touches the page number box. Using `pagewidth` makes the headrule across the page. How do I subtract marginpar from this and make it start from text.
   [image]
2. I am using a coloured box for displaying page number, there is a slight gap between the headrule and the page number box. How can this gap be eliminated?  `headwidth=paper` helps to push this box to the end of the page.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[headwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}




 \KOMAoptions{headsepline=1pt:\pagewidth}




\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\leftmark\quad\pagemark}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
 \colorbox{black}{%
 \makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax][l]{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}%
}}}



\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First things first}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Second things second}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your example does not compile using pdfLaTeX. However, if I understand correctly what you want, you want something like `clines,headsepline=1pt:text` and maybe also `plainheadsepline`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[headwidth=paper,clines,headsepline=1pt:text,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\leftmark\quad\pagemark}% Not sure, that this is really, what you want.
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
 \colorbox{black}{%
 \makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax][l]{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}%
}}}



\begin{document}


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First things first}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Second things second}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: with original \ohead]

But maybe your want this:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}% Note: scrreport is only a wrapper to scrreprt.
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[automark,headwidth=paper,clines,headsepline=1pt:text,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\headmark\hskip\marginparsep\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
 \colorbox{black}{%
 \makebox[\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2-\marginparsep-2\fboxsep\relax][l]{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}%
}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First things first}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Second things second}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: corrected width of elements and automatic mark]

Same could be achieved using:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}% Note: scrreport is only a wrapper to scrreprt.
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\headmark\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep
    \colorbox{black}{%
      \makebox[\dimeval{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2-\marginparsep}][l]{%
        \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}
      }}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First things first}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Second things second}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

which is IMHO somehow easier.

To increase height or depth of the black box, you just would have to increase the height or depth of the content of the `\colorbox`, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}% Note: scrreport is only a wrapper to scrreprt.
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[automark,ilines,headsepline=1pt:\paperwidth-2.5cm,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\headmark\pagemark}
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep
    \colorbox{black}{%
      \makebox[\dimeval{(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2-\marginparsep}][l]{%
        \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{2pt}%
      }}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First things first}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Second things second}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think, with these three alternatives you now have all information to get the result you want, even if you'd need more modifications.

Note: The idea to use a `\makebox[0pt][l]{…}` to move the number into the margin is from [“How to separate the page number in the head with a vertical line”](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_PaginationSeparatorInHead/) (also [available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_PaginationSeparatorInHead/)).